# Scroll to the top of the screen without refencing to the parent window

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a form being loaded inside another form that is part of another application (it is also in another domain).

My problem is that I'd like to scroll to the top of the screen (also the top of the "container part" of the screen).

I can already scroll to the top of the inside form using the following line of code:

```
window.document.body.scrollIntoView(true);
```

or, alternatively:

```
document.getElementById("{idOfTheFrame}").focus();
```

How could I workaround to scroll to the top of the container form if I cannot reference it?

Is there a way to set the absolute position of the scroll on the browser? Do you have any other idea to solve the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: `form inside another form that is part of another application in another domain` <- That sounds like your problem, complicating things. How are these forms inside forms from other domains included in the original page ?

Comment: Are we talking about iframes?

Comment: hi, the container form belongs to an application that is responsible for the authentication and authorization of the users. Once the user logs in, he can call the insider application and its aspx is loaded inside an iframe. Did I answer your question? Do you need more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could find to the problem was searching the already rendered elements with

```
console.log(document.all);
```

So, I could later use:

```
document.all("<element I found that was already rendered>").focus();
```

In my case, I used:

```
document.all("container").focus();
```

Through this solution, I couldn't focus on the top of the page, but I could focus on the top of the application being load inside.